# concatenate dataframes vertically

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I want to concatenate dataframes vertically. Each dataframe I have is created from a file in a directory and I want to concatenate all of them.
I can do this for each individual file:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Desktop/folder/file1.csv', usecols = 'name')
df2 = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/Desktop/folder/file1.csv', usecols = 'reads')

result = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

But, I'd have to do this for each individual file at a time. I tried saving the values in an empty array like this:

```
for file in glob.glob('C:/Users/Desktop/folder/file*.csv'):

    df1 = pd.read_csv(file, usecols='name')
    df2 = pd.read_csv(file, usecols='reads')

    collected_columns.append(df1['name'])
    collected_columns.append(df2['reads'])
    
final_df = pd.concat(df1, df2, join='outer', axis=1, sort=True)

# dataframe to csv
final_df.to_csv('C:/Users/Desktop/folder/TEST.csv')
```

but this keeps resulting in a dataframe with each column from each file side by side. I hope this makes sense, if anyone can help I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: if you provide some examples of your data and expected output, people can help you better!

Comment: as the final result, do you want to have just two columns `'name'`  and `'reads'` with all the values from all the files?

Comment: Hi @HooriM.I was just going to reply to first question but this is exactly what i'm hoping to achieve. One thing, there are different values in each of these columns (although, same column titles for each file) and the number of values also differs per file. I wonder if that's also why I'm unable to get these columns to concatenate properly. Please let me know if I can provide more info, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's assume that result of first concatenation is as follows:

```
first_concat = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
    name    reads
0   Joe     1
1   Jack    2
2   John    3
```

And you have another file based on which you have another concatenation (the same code as the first file):

```
second_concat = pd.concat([df3, df4], axis=1)

    name    reads
0   Ava     11
1   Adam    22
```

In order to concat these two vertically, you should do:

```
all_df = [first_concat, second_concat]
final_df = pd.concat(all_df, ignore_index=True)

    name    reads
0   Joe     1
1   Jack    2
2   John    3
3   Ava     11
4   Adam    22
```

Then you can use it in your `for loop` easily:

```
all_df = []
for file in glob.glob('C:/Users/Desktop/folder/file*.csv'):
    df1 = pd.read_csv(file, usecols='name')
    df2 = pd.read_csv(file, usecols='reads')
    df_nr_concat = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
    all_df.append(df_nr_concat)
final_df = pd.concat(all_df, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: This is perfect, it worked on my test files!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Here I'm providing code with output:

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

example_data_1 = {
    'Name': ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charlie'],
    'Age': [25, 30, 35],
    'Salary': [50000, 60000, 70000]
}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(example_data_1)

example_data_2 = {
    'Name': ['David', 'Emily', 'Frank'],
    'Age': [28, 22, 33],
    'Salary': [72000, 48000, 53000]
}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(example_data_2)

Concatenated_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
print("Concatenated DataFrame:")
print(Concatenated_df)
```

**Output:**

```
Concatenated DataFrame:
Name  Age  Salary
0    Alice   25   50000
1      Bob   30   60000
2  Charlie   35   70000
3    David   28   72000
4    Emily   22   48000
5    Frank   33   53000
```